# How to make state/company field in new customer creation required from admin panel?

Tags: customer, customer-address

How to make the company field and state field in the address form (in admin panel, Customer->Manage Customer->new Customers) mandatory when a user is created. I tried to find a phtml corresponding to the form, but dint find any. 
Also how to make just the js validation for the company and state field?

Answer (score 3):

The customer fields are based on [EAV](http://www.solvingmagento.com/magento-eav-system/) which means an individual field can't be found in the template files but is stored in the database as an attribute.

In this case it's the `customer_eav_attribute` table. But first you'll need to know the attribute ID. For that check the `eav_attribute` table, locate your attribute and use the `attribute_id` value to locate the correct row in the `customer_eav_attribute` table.
Also set `is_required` to **1** for this attribute in the table.

If you take a look at the `customer_eav_attribute` table you'll see a couple of columns, for your question the `validate_rules` column is the important one. It contains a serialized array with the types of validation.

To make a field simply required adding `a:2:{s:15:"max_text_length";i:255;s:15:"min_text_length";i:1;}` should be enough.

I haven't tested this so I'd suggest testing it on a development environment first.

Comment: how about setting `is_required=1` where `attribute_code=company` in the table `eav_attribute`

Comment: but this will make the company field required at all the places, frontend and backend as well.

Comment: is_required error is comming, so once the user enter everything and press save, after reloading magento will show the error. 
But the js validation is not working by modifying the validate rules.

Comment: Surprisingly some fields are without the validation rules in db are required fields!!!